# Angular Foundation Directives templateUrl Property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation

I'm using angular-foundation (http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/) that leverages angular directives for implementing Foundation things like Modals, Tabs and other front-end services.

The problem I'm having is that all of the directives have pre-populated "templateUrl" attributes that do not exist on my server. Also, because this is an external dependency managed with Bower, I can't manually update the library. I pulled out the following directive from the library:

```
angular.module('mm.foundation.tabs', [])
    .directive('tabset', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: 'TabsetController',
        templateUrl: 'template/tabs/tabset.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.vertical = angular.isDefined(attrs.vertical) ? scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.vertical) : false;
          scope.justified = angular.isDefined(attrs.justified) ? scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.justified) : false;
          scope.type = angular.isDefined(attrs.type) ? scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.type) : 'tabs';
        }
      };
    })
```

from my module I claim a dependency on the mm.foundation module:

```
angular.module('foundationDemoApp', ['mm.foundation.tabs']).controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:"Dynamic Title 1", content:"Dynamic content 1" },
    { title:"Dynamic Title 2", content:"Dynamic content 2" }
  ];

  $scope.alertMe = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("You've selected the alert tab!");
    });
  };
})
```

I'm currently using Gulp with gulp-html2js to bundle my templates. On the github README they mention customizing templates (https://github.com/pineconellc/angular-foundation) something about the $templateCache, but at this point I am not sure how to change the templateUrl defined in the library to my template's location.

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this not working otherwise? Angular libraries include an inline template with an id that may look like a URL, but is just used as an Id to locate the template in the `$templateCache`

Answer (score 1):

Since no one answered, I'll give it a shot, it'll may help you, ossys (note to any moderator, feel free to remove my answer if I'm wrong).

If you `bower install`ed the library, those templates should be somewhere in `bower_components/angular-foundation`, you should follow their example https://github.com/pineconellc/angular-foundation#customize-templates and get something like :

```
html2js: {
  options: {
    base: '.',
    module: 'ui-templates',
    rename: function (modulePath) {
      var moduleName = modulePath.replace('bower_components/angular-foundation', '').replace('.html', '');
      return 'template' + '/' + moduleName + '.html';
    }
  },
  main: {
    src: ['bower_components/angular-foundation/**/*.html'],
    dest: '.tmp/ui-templates.js'
  }
}
//or in gulp
gulp.src('bower_components/angular-foundation/**/*.html')
  .pipe(html2js({
    outputModuleName: 'ui-templates'
  }))
  .pipe(concat('ui-templates.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
```

Answer (score 1):

With $templateCache i think it is possible like this to replace the template with ur own

for tab:

`<script type="text/ng-template" id="template/tabs/tabset.html" 
  src="/path/to/your/template.html"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Hey thank you guys for your answer and actually you both are correct.

My problem is I was thinking of the solution backwards. Rather than replacing the templateUrl parameter for each directive, in my case I instead need to rename the name of the template I'm compiling. For example....

I am using gulp and html2js to bundle my template files. Before importing angular-foundation my templates task looked something like this:

```
gulp.task('templates', function (cb) {

           gulp.src('path/to/tempalates/**/*.html')
             .pipe(html2js({
               outputModuleName: 'my.templates',
               base: './src/web/',
             }))
             .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
             .pipe(insert.prepend("var angular = require('angular');"))
             .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/web/'))
             .on('end', done);
         };
});
```

I went ahead and uploaded the html template directory from angular-foundation github repository, and put that in the path 'path/to/foundation/template'. I then updated the templates gulp task so that it would rename the 'path/to/foundation/template' path to the path that is already coded in the directive. For example, if a directive is expecting a templateUrl of 'template/tab/tabs.html' and the location of the actual template is 'path/to/foundation/template/tab/tabs.html', then the rename function would replace 'path/to/foundation' with an empty string to make the path 'template/tab/tabs.html' during the build. My final gulp task now looks like:

```
gulp.task('templates', function (cb) {
           gulp.src('path/to/tempalates/**/*.html','path/to/foundation/template/**/*.html'])
             .pipe(html2js({
               outputModuleName: 'my.templates',
               base: './src/web/',
               rename : function (modulePath) {
                  var moduleName = modulePath.replace('path/to/foundation/', '').replace('.html', '');
                  return moduleName + '.html';
                }
             }))
             .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
             .pipe(insert.prepend("var angular = require('angular');"))
             .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/web/'))
             .on('end', done);
         };
});
```

So now all my templates are built with the path that angular-foundation expects them to be at, and I'm not stuck trying to manage template paths during run time.

I hope this helps others!